# custom node-red-node socket.io client makes connection but crashed when data is received?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-red

I’m new to Node-Red and socket.io. I would like to build a custom node to work as a client receiveing socket.io messages from a server. I’m calling it socketi, as it’s just input. The node starts out operational, makes the connection fine, but crashes when I send data from another client to the server to the deployed Node-Red flow. Here’s the node’s js:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
  "use strict";
  var socket = require("socket.io-client");
  var io = require("socket.io-client");
  function socketiNode(config) {
    RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
    var node = this;
    socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.3:8080');
    socket.on('mouse',
        function(data) {
            // When we receive data
            this.warn([ data.x , data.y ]);
            this.send([ data.x , data.y ]);
         }
     );
  }
 RED.nodes.registerType("socketi",socketiNode);
}
```

After trial and error I discovered a connection is made when I require the variables for “socket.io-clinet” rather than “socket.io”. It still needs other modules so I have the following in the node_modules folder:

```
/node_modules
  /debug
  /engine.io
  /has-binary-data
  /socket.io-adapter
  /socket.io-client
  /socket.io-parser
```

I have the socket.io server and another client running on a Mac and the Node-Red flow deployed on a Raspberry Pi 2, both local. Here’s what happens when I run Node-Red:

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node-red-pi --max-old-space-size=128 -v


    Welcome to Node-RED
    ===================

    2 Aug 19:58:22 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.11.1
    2 Aug 19:58:22 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.12.0
    2 Aug 19:58:22 - [info] Loading palette nodes
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] Settings file  : /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/settings.js
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] User directory : /home/pi/.node-red
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] Flows file : /home/pi/.node-red/flows_raspberrypi.json
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] Starting flows
    2 Aug 19:58:32 - [info] Started flows
    2 Aug 19:58:41 - [info] Stopping flows
    2 Aug 19:58:41 - [info] Stopped flows
    2 Aug 19:58:41 - [info] Starting flows
    2 Aug 19:58:41 - [info] Started flows
    2 Aug 19:59:36 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
    2 Aug 19:59:36 - TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/socketi.js:12:22)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Socket.onevent (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:254:10)
    at Socket.onpacket (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:212:12)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Manager.ondecoded (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:301:8)
    at Decoder.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/home/pi/.node-red/nodes/node-red-node-socketi/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

19:59:36 is where I send data from client to server to Node-Red. Seems clear that I need more modules even though I think I should only need the client code. Maybe I’m just missing something simple?

Comment: You may do better asking questions like this on the mailing list as it will allow for more back and forth. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in the `function(data)` will not point to the node object but the socket call back object. Try making this change:

```
...
var node = this;
socket = io.connect('http://192.168.2.3:8080');
socket.on('mouse',
    function(data) {
        // When we receive data
        node.warn([ data.x , data.y ]);
        node.send([ data.x , data.y ]);
     }
 );
 ...
```

Comment: Ah! That fixed it. Very much obliged.